# the best way to codeigniter website multi-language CMS implement

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm researching hours and hours, but I could not find any clear, efficient way to make it :/

I have a codeigniter base website in English and I have to add a spainsh, portuguese  language now. What is the best way to make my site in 3 language depending visitor selection?

all menu and footer and also content also translate when language change so which way is best for me.

Comment: From User guide http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/language.html#handling-multiple-languages

Answer (score 0):

In codeigniter it is easy to implement multi language website.

For that you have to just make Language folder under the application and make necessary files for each language.

For further reference you can visit this sites :

[multi-language-implementation-in-codeigniter](http://www.codexworld.com/multi-language-implementation-in-codeigniter/)

Comment: content also change not only menu , footer

Comment: your thinking is right but when content change that time problem create

Answer (score 0):

There is a library available for it **Language files are typically stored in your system/language directory**

**From Document :**

> The Language Class provides functions to retrieve language files and
>   lines of text for purposes of internationalization.
>
> In your CodeIgniter system folder you'll find one called language
>   containing sets of language files. You can create your own language
>   files as needed in order to display error and other messages in other
>   languages.
>
> Language files are typically stored in your system/language directory.
>   Alternately you can create a folder called language inside your
>   application folder and store them there. CodeIgniter will look first
>   in your application/language directory. If the directory does not
>   exist or the specified language is not located there CI will instead
>   look in your global system/language folder.

- You need to create a lang1.php and lang2.php inside
  application/language/lang then create your keys inside that file
  Like $lang['abc'] = "def"; then load it in your controller like
  $this->lang->load('lang1', 'polish'); then fetch the line like
  $this->lang->line('abc');

I didn't tried but it will definitely work if not worked then let me know.

**EDIT :**

Store data of spainsh in both variable's data are stored in system/language directory,

```
$lang1['spainsh'] = "content of spanish"
$lang2['portuguese'] = "content of portuguese "
```

Then call those content in your controller and then use it in your view. 
There is no other options available. Because CI's library will not change your language you have to put content for it languagewise diffrent brother this is the only solution.

Comment: but usme blog system apply karni hey Ok ??

Comment: now when user can read particular blog post then his change language so also this blog post content only change

Comment: manu and footer easily change but how change particular blog content ??

Comment: @HothiJimit need to be in english these comments

Comment: sorry @wolfgang1983 bro

Comment: You can add data from admin panel using dropdown list language wise. First call the library of lang1 grab data of lang1 using $this->load->library('lang1'). Then call the data from database from model do some logic for id.

Comment: blog post in 3 language Ok when add in database that time 3 entry insert in database this entry id is different ok

Comment: brother If you are not clear now  then please read  document regarding making custom library and access of system/language directory  because this is the only solution as per my knowledge

Comment: ohk so when language change you have to make a ajax call or normal code then get id of that language and in database you have to make table of language and compare that dropdown's id with database language id if lang1 selected then load that library and in library content are stored in $lang1 = "content". similar for second try with this logic it will 100% work